# How do I remove those numbers from Kubuntu's task manager?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I want to remove those numbers from panel whenever I open same app multiple times.

[image]

Comment: You are asking for something that serves no purpose. That kind of numbering appears only if the windows are identical. For example, in your image, you have two "new tabs" in separate windows. It's like when opening text documents - you have Untitled 1 and Untitled 2. If you simply remove the numbering you cannot tell any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: I afraid you can't remove only `<2>` or `<3>` from appearing. There has to be a way to distinguish windows.

There is a workaround which I like and that is to use an *alternate* task manager which is available by default on a normal Kubuntu 18.04 system.

First, I see what you see with the default task manager with three Google Chrome windows:

[image: Default task manager with three Google Chrome windows]

With the default task manager, there is a way to collapse the three separate entries into one. See [the answer by cipricus](https://askubuntu.com/a/1114172/248158) for more detail:

[image: Groups a program's entries together]

I prefer the alternate task manager widget<sup>*</sup> known as the *Icons-only Task Manager*:

[image: Icons-only Task Manager widget]

<sup>*</sup>Note: to access the available widgets, click on the ☰ icon usually located at the right-end or bottom of your panel.

I also prefer a vertical panel and the images below are with a vertical panel:

Icons-only Task Manager with **one** Google Chrome window

[image: Icons-only Task Manager with one Google Chrome window]

Icons-only Task Manager with **three** Google Chrome windows

[image: Icons-only Task Manager with three Google Chrome windows]

Notice the little green circle with a white plus-sign next to the Google Chrome icon. That indicates the presence of more than one window open for a particular program. The three entries to the right of the Google Chrome icon are there because I single left-clicked on the icon. I can then select the window I want to maximize (or whatever). Otherwise, those entries are not visible.

Comment: The right-click *More actions > Allow this program to be grouped* setting means that the grouping will be *allowed* in case the task manager is full, because the default setting is to group only then. To *always* group, right click, *Configure Task Manager (Task Manager Settings) > General* and un-check "Only group when taskbar is full". Then, you already get the benefit 
 provided by "icon only" widget.

Comment: Interesting! That option is absent from the icons-only task manager config. I'll edit my answer to point that out.

Comment: `click on the ☰ icon usually located at the right-end or bottom of your panel` - that icon appears only if widgets are not locked. Right click the desktop or the panel to switch that. But in order to configure the task manager or any other widget you don't need to unlock the widgets: just right click the specific widget.

Answer (score 1):

(As a complement to the @DKBose's answer; as there is no way and no point in removing the numbers, I am just commenting on the setting to *group* the task manager windows of the same program).

The  right-click *More actions > Allow this program to be grouped* setting means that the grouping will be *allowed* in case the task manager is full, because the default setting is to group only then. To *always* group, right click, *Configure Task Manager (Task Manager Settings) > General* and *un-check* "Only group when taskbar is full".

[image]